# Syntax for pushing text of child of current element to array

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery I have selected the text in the fourth child element of the **current** element in the loop.

This selection seems okay

```
 $(this).children().eq(3).text();
```

But when trying to push it to an array, this line gives the error "myArray.push.$ is not a function":

```
myArray.push.$(this).children().eq(3).text();
```

and if adding parentheses like this, I get the error "SyntaxError: unexpected token (

```
myArray.push.($(this).children().eq(3).text());
```

Can't I do it on one line? Do I have to set a variable for the selection and then push the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, myArray.push.($(this).children().eq(3).text()) has an extra "." between push and the beginning of the parenthesis.

So, try:

```
myArray.push($(this).children().eq(3).text());
```

Comment: Great. Somehow I didn't notice it.

Comment: Thanks for doing that, it does help a lot.